# Introduction to the Python Clutter bindings?

Tags: python, user-interface, binding, clutter-gui

I've had a search around but I haven't been able to find decent online tutorials for the recent clutter bindings. There are guides for 0.4 and 0.6 around but 0.8 is supposed to be very different making these guides kind of useless. Links or examples greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[these docs](http://files.majorsilence.com/rubbish/pygtk-book/pygtk-notebook-html/pygtk-notebook-latest.html#SECTION001000000000000000000) seem to be pretty up to date.

Comment: Cheers - short answer with the info required :)

Comment: @Eliot, so why not upvote as well as accept? It's rare to see one without the other!-)

Comment: Sorry - totally forgot - theres the vote for ya.

Comment: Updated link: http://www.majorsilence.com/pygtk_clutter